# $f:\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}\ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^2$ for which $f_x(x,y)=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$ and $f_y(x,y)=\frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Is there exists $f:\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}\ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^2$ for which $f_x(x,y)=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$ and $f_y(x,y)=\frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$? I thought $\arctan(x/y)$ would be ok, but the answer to that question is negative. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the complex version of $$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z} $$, which we know integrates to $i2\pi$. If there was an antiderive , the integral (since it is being done over a closed contour) would integrate to zero.

EDIT: Re Rene Schiperus' comment, while a local, $C^2$ antiderivative exists, satisfying the necessary differentiability conditions, but the fact that the integral does not integrate to $0$ shows that a global antiderivative does not exist.

An antiderivative would be a global argument function on $\mathbb R^2$, which is not even globally continuous.

Comment: Does not this show that there is no well defined anti derivative regardless of differentiability requirements ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: Precisely, if there was an antiderivative, it would integrate to zero.

Comment: Ok, but there is a locally defined anti derivative.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: I agree, there is a locally-defined one, but not a globally-defined one. The integral over any curve that avoids the origin would be a local antiderivative.

Comment: I am not sure where to post this, but, to summerize there is a local anti derivative, given by the OP, and it is $C^2$, and its mixed partials are equal. So the issue is not the differeniabliy conditions, but rather global definition, which is not possible since the line interval around the origin is not zero, contrary to Green's theorem. (or its complex formulation).

Comment: If I may, with your permission, I can include it in my answer, giving you credit for it.

Comment: Yes please do. I think your answer is the right answer.

Comment: @Rene Schipperus: Just edited it in.